# Django static files 404 not found nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-staticfiles

I am developing a Django application and I want to put it online on DigitalOcean so I can show it to a remote future user. I am quite new to django and python and I have never in my life touched the deployment of web applications, so I'm a bit lost in all that.

I used the one-click install of a django droplet in digitalocean, which uses nginx and gunicorn. I was able to make the app load in the browser using the ip address (159.203.58.210), but the problem is that no static files can be loaded.

I googled that for some days and nothing could help me. I'm guessing it has something to do with either permissions not allowed or that I did not write the static files correcly in my templates and *.py files.

I'm running my application with the command:

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:9000
```

I'm using sqlite3 as db

My complete code is here:
https://github.com/gbastien1/carte-interactive

On the server, my app is at /home/django/international 
(where international is my site name, the app is called carte_interactive)

My staticfiles settings in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= '/home/django/international/carte_interactive/static'
```

my staticfiles settings in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf (same for media)

```
location /static {
    alias /home/django/international/carte_interactive/static;
}
```

In my templates, I use {`% load staticfiles %}`
And I call my static files like so:

```
{% static 'carte_interactive/css/style.css' %}
```

And in my .py files, I sometimes call those files like this, which I don't know if it's right:

```
app_name='carte_interactive'
json_data_url = static('carte_interactive/json/data.json')
json_data_file = open(app_name + json_data_url, 'w') <-- here
```

It was the only solution that worked on development to access my static files in views.py, but it might be a problem in production with collectstatic and all, I don't know.

I am using django 1.9.4 on server and 1.9.1 on development it seems.

Do you have any idea why my staticfiles are 404 not found on the server but everything works fine on development?

Could there be a permission issue with the folder /home/django/... for the browser to reach my static files?

Is there a better way to call my staticfiles in views.py?

Thanks in advance!

**edit:**
The console error I get for all my template static files:

> http://159.203.58.210/static/carte_interactive/css/style.css Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of manage.py runserver. That is for development only; I hope you are not using it on DigitalOcean.

Comment: All I want is for my application to be available online, so yes, I'm using runserver on digitalocean and it works. The only problem is the staticfiles. I will take care of using gunicorn or something else for real production later.

Comment: Is it nginx that gives you 404 error? I usually use trailing slashes in all directory names and aliases in my nginx configs. Don't really know if it makes any difference, though.

Comment: I assume that you don't use nginx to serve static assets in development? Runserver can serve static files, but very much slower than nginx, which becomes a problem once you have more than a single web site visitor at a time. You can remove the nginx alias for static and reload nginx to let runserver serve the files, to confirm whether it's a problem in the nginx config.

Comment: I commented out the location /static { ... } block in django.conf and no change. Did that make sure that the files were served by runserver or is there another way ?

And also, the error the console gives me is this:
`http://159.203.58.210/static/carte_interactive/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Oh and for the trailing slashes, I used the default file and only changed the path to the static files, so I guess it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ok I forgot the reload part. It works without nginx. But it does not load every files. Ann my lib files like jquery and bootstrap which are in a lib folder in static folder are not loaded, but my css is :/

Edit: I just don't have my files on the server for some reason, my bad ! Thanks for the quick answer !

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that you don't use nginx to serve static assets in
>   development? Runserver can serve static files, but very much slower
>   than nginx, which becomes a problem once you have more than a single
>   web site visitor at a time. You can remove the nginx alias for static
>   and reload nginx to let runserver serve the files, to confirm whether
>   it's a problem in the nginx config.
>   Håken Lid

I removed nginx and made the Django server load the static files, and now I can show it to my future users. This answered my question, though it did not solve the problem itself! Thanks anyway !